# Factory Bot: Pass same object to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot

Model has 2 associations.  Each association belongs to the same "group".  How do we pass the same group to each association?

```
factory :group_feature_config do
  transient do
    group
  end
  association :group_feature, factory: :group_feature, group: group
  association :group_user, factory: :group_user, group: group
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
factory :group_feature_config do
  transient do
    group
  end
  group_feature { association :group_feature, group_id: group.id }
  group_user { association :group_user, group_id: group.id }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works for me:

```
factory :group_feature_config do
  group_feature
  group_user { association :group_user, group: group_feature.group }
end
```

assuming the `group_feature` factory sets up a `group`